# Localization in Swift

Tags: swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have two languages for my app. 
One is English and the other is Chinese.
When I switch off the English language and then press on Back button, the other pages are not translated to Chinese automatically. 
It only changes when we pull down the page to make refresh. 
I don't know how it happens. 
Please explain me how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If the pages are already loaded in memory, the label's text will not be updated when you are going back to the page.

So yin have two options :

1. Create a setup method, which will be called when the `viewWillAppear`

   - +Easy to implement
   - - Will be called even if there is no changes
2. Create custom components registering for a Notification. when you change language, fire the Notification

   - + This will perform action only when required
   - - A bit more complicated to implement

You can also mix the 2 of these, posting a notification which will be call the `setup` method on all loaded controllers.

Comment: Where should I implement that viewWillAppear code in Language.swift or before that view page?

Comment: Il ll your VC, that's why second way is better, even if harder to implement